# I am able to access iframe contents only once in this code

Tags: jquery

I have used the below code to access iframe contents but it is not working more than once..

```
 var str = "http://***/";
 $('body').append('<iframe id="ifr" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%" src="' + str + $('#htmNum').val() + '.html"></iframe>');
    document.domain = "****.com";
    $('#ifr').load(function () {
        var body = $('#ifr').contents().find('body');
        body.find('img').each(function () {
            var path = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', str + path.split('/')[path.split('/').length - 1]);
        });
        alert(body.find('img').length); // Is not working
 });
```

Someone please help me on this.

Comment: when you say it's not working what is the result and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing iframe load function

```
 var str = "http://***/";
 $('body').append('<iframe id="ifr" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%" src="' + str + $('#htmNum').val() + '.html"></iframe>');
    document.domain = "****.com";
        var body = $('#ifr').contents().find('body');
        body.find('img').each(function () {
            var path = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', str + path.split('/')[path.split('/').length - 1]);
        });
        alert(body.find('img').length); // Is not working
```

**EDITED**

```
var str = "http://***/";
 $('body').append('<iframe id="ifr" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%" src="' + str + $('#htmNum').val() + '.html"></iframe>');
    document.domain = "****.com";
        var body = $('#ifr').contents();
        body.find('img').each(function () {
            var path = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', str + path.split('/')[path.split('/').length - 1]);
        });
        alert(body.find('img').length); // must work now
```